# Mongodb and Node: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936 throw err

Tags: node.js, mongodb, git-bash

I am getting an error from a Node app. I search from internet but no solution found, everything is same like video I have watched, in video there is no err, but in my code this error occurred again and again,

- My question is what is err assertion
- how to deal with this err,
- why this problem occurred to me

This is my app.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'fruitsDB';

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  // Insert a single document
  db.collection('inserts').insertOne({a:1}, function(err, r) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);

    // Insert multiple documents
    db.collection('inserts').insertMany([{a:2}, {a:3}], function(err, r) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
      assert.equal(2, r.insertedCount);

      client.close();
    });
  });
});
```

when I type to gitbash node app.js this err occured
this is console

```
$ node app.js
Connected correctly to server
node:assert:123
  throw new AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: 1 == undefined
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\app.js:21:12
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:5
10:9
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations
\execute_operation.js:48:55
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:5
10:9
    at completeEndSession (D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mo
ngodb\lib\sessions.js:147:17)
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sessions.j
s:157:13
    at maybePromise (D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\
lib\utils.js:496:5)
    at ClientSession.endSession (D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modu
les\mongodb\lib\sessions.js:133:41)
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations
\execute_operation.js:48:36
    at D:\text editor\web_pros\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations
\insert.js:53:13 {
  generatedMessage: true,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: 1,
  expected: undefined,
  operator: '=='
}
```

I watch older videos and try to connect app to database. maybe there is some updates

Answer (score 1):

The result of the method [`insertOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertOne/) doesn't have the property `insertedCount` because if it succeeds the number of inserted documents will by definition be `1`.

If the database can't insert the document, it will call the callback with a non-null error. This applies to both general errors as well as duplicate keys.

Therefore the `assert.equal(null, err)` already checks for what you want `assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount)` to check. You can just remove that `insertedCount` assertion.

Note that the `insertedCount` property exists for [`insertMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/insertMany/), so the assertion there is valid.

Comment: Thank you, but I take this code from documentation, Anyway thank you I'll try